# How Do I fill all blanks with "0" or "NO DATA" when already using a google sheet query function

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

I have used a google sheet query formula to move data to one sheet, however, there are blanks here, and these blanks do not sit well with Looker when uploading. So how do I go about keeping my formula and then filling all the blanks with a value of either "0" or "No Data"

This is my current formula

```
=QUERY({'2023-Q1'!A2:KO;'2023-Q2'!A2:KO;'2023-Q3'!A2:KO;'2023-Q4'!A2:KO},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

So how do I add to this query formula so I can still pull the information from the other sheet and also fill the blanks with "No data" or "0"

Unfortunately I cannot share the data, but the data will have whole columns with blanks and some columns with filled rows, and blanks cells. So there is spottiness.

So far I tried and array with a query inside a query, but I must of been doing it wrong.

What I am expecting is to be able to do file > replace current sheet from example Q3. and then have the master sheet (which holds a query to gather Q1-Q4 data) populate it and also fill the blanks, so google data studio doesn't give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the whole QUERY inside an ARRAYFORMULA and replace empty cells with each value:

```
=LET(q,
  QUERY({'2023-Q1'!A2:KO;'2023-Q2'!A2:KO;'2023-Q3'!A2:KO;'2023-Q4'!A2:KO},"select * where Col1 is not null",0),
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(q="","No Data",q)))
```

---

UPDATE:

to filter empty columns and complete empty cells with different values according on types of data of that column:

```
=LET(range,QUERY(.............),
woempty,FILTER(range,BYCOL(range,LAMBDA(each,COUNTA(each)))),
typenum,BYCOL(woempty, LAMBDA(each,COUNT(each)>(COUNTA(each)/2))),
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(woempty="",IF(typenum,0,"No Data"),woempty)))
```

Place the QUERY inside the first line

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That worked beautifully. The problem I ran into after putting it, in is that data studio still didn't recognize the headers as unique (although they are). As well as those values that where numbers did not like the "No Data".  I read somewhere that the blank columns need to be removed if there are. So I wonder if anyone knows how to remove all blank columns in one go and add "zeros" to number value columns and "no data" to text values. This will help a lot. If possible, the raw code, and a code that will complement the string above.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how your data looks. But for any case, if you need to filter empty columns and determine type of data, I'll add a formula in the update of my answer. Check it out